# Co-relation Coefficient

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables. Their probability density function is: 
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}2x & \mbox{if } x\in [0,1], y\in[0,1] 
\\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Calculate the co-relation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$.

I know that $\mathsf{Corr}(X,Y) = \dfrac{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(x)\,\mathsf{Var}(y)\,}}$ but I'm not sure how to get those values.

Comment: and where do you have difficulties?

Comment: I have the formula Corr(x,y) = Cov(x,y)/(sqrt(Var(x)Var(Y)) but im not sure how to calculate those with the given information.

Comment: so first $x$ and $y$ is different from $X$ and $Y$. Second, if you are given the joint density you can calculate the marginal densities right?

Comment: @StatsHelp, just a bit of advice: it's good you have a starting point with the Corr(x,y) formula. You might want to add that to your question, so others know you started somewhere.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I calculated the marginals f(x) = 2x and f(y) = 1.

Comment: good so now you have marginals. This means you can simply calculate $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$, $\mu_X$, $\mu_Y$ and any other moments w.r.t. $X$ and $Y$. Can you use this information to calculate Cocariance? What does it say when you see $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$?

Comment: I found Var(X) to be 1/18 and Var(Y) to be 1/12. Is this correct so far?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I've calculated a final value of -0.979796. Is this correct?

Comment: check the webpage I gave you in the answer. Have a look at "Expectation and covariance" and see your mistake in your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
f(x,y) & = \begin{cases}2x & \mbox{if } (x,y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1] 
\\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise }\end{cases}
\\[2ex]
f_X(x) & = \int_0^1 2x\operatorname d y \\ & = 2x
\\[2ex]
f_Y(y) & = \int_0^1 2x\operatorname d x \\ & = 1
\\[3ex]
\therefore f(x,y) & = f_X(x)f_Y(y) & \text{so what does this mean?}
\\[4ex]
\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) & = \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)
\\[1ex] & = (\text{what?}) & \text{and why?}  
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this web-pages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)

you will find the answer to your question.